# Using mongo cluster with PHP, how could PHP pick the right server

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongo primary + slave cluster, and a PHP server. The PHP server does both read and write operation.

However, mongo does not allow write operation on slaves. I can't simply use a auto-balance system like haproxy.

If I had to manually choose what server to write to and what server to read from, it would then be stupid.

So, what's the best practice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to move out of master-slave and use replica sets.

> MongoDB 3.2 deprecates the use of master-slave replication for
>   components of sharded clusters.
>
> [Replica sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) replace master-slave replication for most use cases. If
>   possible, use replica sets rather than master-slave replication for
>   all new production deployments.

Replica Sets provides all the functionality of master-slave deployments, replica sets are also more robust for production use. Master-slave replication preceded replica sets and made it possible to have a large number of non-master (i.e. slave) nodes, as well as to restrict replicated operations to only a single database; however, master-slave replication provides less redundancy and does not automate failover.

Please see

[Deploy Master-Slave Equivalent using Replica Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/#replica-set-equivalent)

[Convert a Master-Slave Deployment to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/#convert-master-slave-to-replica-set)